# Getting setting cookies on different domains, with JavaScript or other

Tags: javascript, dns, cookies

I need to set/get the cookies stored at `first.example` while browsing `second.example`, I have full access of `first.example` but I only have JavaScript access (can manipulate the DOM as I want) on `second.example`.

My first approach was to create an iframe on `second.example` (with JS) that loaded a page like `first.example/doAjax?setCookie=xxx` and that did an AJAX call to say `first.example/setCookie?cookieData=xxx` which would set the cookie on `first.example` with the data we passed around.

That pretty much worked fine for setting the cookie on `first.example` from `second.example` - for getting a cookie I basically followed the same procedure, created the iframe that loaded `first.example/doAjax?getCookie` and that would do an AJAX call to say `first.example/getCookie` which would read the cookie info on `first.example` and return it as a JSON object.

The problem is that I'm unable to bring that JSON cookie object back to `second.example` so I can read it, well maybe I could just bring it when the AJAX call is complete using "window.top" but there's timing issues because its not relative to when the iframe has been loaded. I hope I am clear and was wondering if there's an easier solution rather than this crazy iframe->ajax crap, also seems like this won't even work for getting cookies in SAFARI.

Comment: Just a note that this is really insecure as anyone could set and get cookies for first.com

Comment: @Luca And if the user had third-party cookies disabled, you won't even be able to set the cookie in the iframe in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could inject a script element into HEAD of the document with a callback that passes the cookie you need to whatever function needs it.

Something like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var newfile=document.createElement('script');
   newfile.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
   newfile.setAttribute("src", 'http://first.com/doAjax?getCookie&callback=passCookie');
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newfile);
 </script>
```

And the page first.com/doAjax?getCookie could do this:

```
     passCookie({'name':'mycookie', 'value':'myvalue'});
```

Comment: I cant use the script tag to read cookies from a different domain, right? I need to actually be on first.com to actually read its cookies, i cant just add a script tag to second.com to get the cookieData... therefore i need to use an iframe, or i dont know... Maybe i didnt understand your answer, let me know.

Comment: You aren't technically using a script tag to read the cookie values, the script is included into your page, therefore it is in the same scope and can call any function on second.com

Comment: Okay, but the script tag evaluates itself on second.com, therefore reading the cookies from second.com, not first.com

Comment: Yes, it is evaluated, but the *contents* of the script is generated on first.com, therefore it can pass the cookie values to second.com

Comment: what really? does that work for setting cookies as well? is it cross-browser?

Comment: Now I know the result of the script tag gets evaluated in the global scope, but what if im returning plain JSON like {"one":"hi"}, how am i suppose to call that if its in the global scope... i guess I could name the object like var myData = {"one":"hi"}, but maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: Apparently this method only works in Firefox, i tested it in Safari and IE6, both didnt seem to be able to set/get cookies...

Comment: Like i said above, this by the way only works in Firefox... any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea what's going on, you'll need to do more debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Put this PHP-File to first.com:

```
//readcookie.php    
echo $_COOKIE['cookiename'];
```

On second.com you can use this javascript to get the value:

```
function readCookieCallback()
{
   if ((this.readyState == 4) && (this.status == 200))
   {
     alert("the value of the cookie is: "+this.responseText);
   } 
   else if ((this.readyState == 4) && (this.status != 200))
   {
     //error...
   }
}


function buttonClickOrAnything()
{
  var refreshObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if (!refreshObject)
  {
    //IE6 or older
    try
    {
      refreshObject = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      try
      {
        refreshObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch (e)
      {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  refreshObject.onreadystatechange = readCookieCallback;
  refreshObject.open("GET", "http://www.first.com/readcookie.php");
  refreshObject.send();
}
```

Regards,
Robert

Comment: Im able to GET cookies fine with the method provided by Ryan Doherty, it seems like it SETs cookies as well on most of the browser except Safari.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I received the response in Chrome: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://second.com/test.php. Origin https://first.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: That's a CORS issue.  Unrelated to the cookie issue.

Answer (score -2):

For SETTING cookies you can change my script as follows:

The new PHP-Script:

```
//writecookie.php
setcookie($_GET['c'], $_GET['v']);
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function buttonClickOrAnything()
{
  var refreshObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if (!refreshObject)
  {
    //IE6 or older
    try
    {
      refreshObject = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      try
      {
        refreshObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch (e)
      {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  refreshObject.open("GET", "http://www.first.com/writecookie.php?c=cookiename&v=cookievalue");
  refreshObject.send();
}
```

That should work on all browsers.

Comment: @LucaMatteis ... as long as CORS (http://dev.w3.org/2006/waf/access-control/) is not enabled.