# PHP session can't be retrieve after redirection using htaccess

Tags: php, session, .htaccess, cookies, redirect

I have done a redirection from `www.abc.com` to `www.def.com` using `.htaccess`.

The redirection is successfull but I have a problem whereby the *cookies* and session can only be accessed when I access the website using `def.com`.
The session will be missing when it is checked from abc.com.

How to copy or read the session at `def.com`?

Please Help me.

Comment: It is difficult - if you could explain WHY you made this re-direction and why you need access to the session data, we may be able to perhaps find an alternative if none of the answers below suit.

Answer (score 0):

well you can't do it simply. Maybe see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402348/getting-setting-cookies-on-different-domains-with-javascript-or-other) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your cookie containing your session id (and therefore, your entire session) is only valid on the domain where it is created. So when you change domains, the cookie is no longer available. To work around this, you could send the session ID to the new domain (which is not very safe, but you might not care), and then creating a new cookie and session for that domain.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "cross site scripting" (XSS) and a lot of people work very hard to make sure that what you want isn't possible. If you do find a way to do it, be sure to let us know, because that would be a MAJOR security breach.

Comment: It's retrieval rather than injection, but it is still attempting to use a script (i.e. 'scripting') to access information across sites; that is the very definition of cross site scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You can only share the same session on both domains when you have access to the session data storage from both servers. Depending on the [session data storage type and location](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path), you might need to write your [own session storage handler](http://php.net/session_set_save_handler).

Besides that, you also need to make sure that the same session ID is used on both domains. If you want to use cookies for the session ID, you can only do it when your domains share a common super-domain, so they are sub-domains of the a domain like *foo.example.com* and *bar.example.com* share the super-domain *example.com*. In that case you need to [adjust the session cookie parameter](http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params) [*domain*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) and set it to value `.example.com` for the super-domain *example.com*.

Otherwise, like in your example where the domains do only share *com* as a top level super domain, you can’t use cookies (in the first place). But you can use the URL to transfer the session ID from one domain to the other domain. To do that you need to enable [*session.use_trans_sid*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid) and disable [*session.use_only_cookies*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-only-cookies) (both at least on the redirection target domain) and append the session ID to every URL pointing from one domain to the other (here you can use the `SID` constant).