# how to get cookies from a different domain with php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cookies

Suppose i have a cookie set in first.com say user. Now i want to read that cookie in second.com through javascript and ajax. But it is not working.I have got xmlHttp.status=0.

sample code

in the second domain readcookie.php file

```
var xmlHttp;
    function createXMLHttpRequest(){
        if(window.ActiveXObject)
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    function readcookie(){

        createXMLHttpRequest(); 
        xmlHttp.open("GET","http://www.first.com/cookie.php",true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=getcookie;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    function getcookie(){
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            if(xmlHttp.status==200){
                var reply=xmlHttp.responseText;
                if(reply){
                    alert(reply);
                }
            }
            else
                alert(xmlHttp.status);
        }
    }
```

in the first domain cookie.php file

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['user'])){
        echo $_COOKIE['user'];
    }
    else{
        setcookie('user','a2345',0);
        echo $_COOKIE['user'];
    }
```

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402348/getting-setting-cookies-on-different-domains-with-javascript-or-other

Comment: Can we arrange that first.com specify that it's cookies can be read by second.com?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't read cookies from another domain - end of.

The only way I can think of is to add some code to the 2nd domain that gets the cookies for you and then to place this in a page on the 1st domain, in an iframe.

You obviously need full access to both domains to be able to do this kind of thing.

Comment: why is that we cant read cookies from another domain using Scripting languages?

Comment: For security reasons.  If you could read cookies from other domains then every site you visit would have access to every cookie on your PC.

Comment: Well "security reasons" is fine. But I guess we can access pro grammatically access other cookies using some of scripting languages or ActiveX sort of things for sure!

Comment: You can only access cookies from the domain to which they belong.  If you have access to the 2nd domain then you can create a script that gets the values for you and use that.  The only way to do it is if you have access to the 2nd domain.

Comment: See the link from Nobita above - it's exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6648/discussion-between-pratik-and-archer)

Comment: @Archer i have access to both domain. so is there any problem in my code

Comment: You can't run ajax across domains either.  I'm afraid there's a lot more to it than that.  You need to run code from domain2 (in an iframe, for example) so that it can get the cookies and pass the values into the parent (main document).  I can only point you in the right direction on this - you're going to need to do some reading on cross-domain security.  Start here... http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Comment: See: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/article.php/c19417/Sharing-Cookies-Across-Domains.htm

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that browsers wont let javascript to access different domain. Add:

```
header('Content-type: text/html');    
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

lines to the beginning of cookie.php and it'll work.
Still, you wont get the cookie (or at least in Chrome). I couldnt yet figure out why. It seems as if chrome creates a new session for the javascript and wont let that session access previous cookies. Like HttpOnly.