# Capture the state of a web page in a URL

Tags: javascript, cookies, web-applications, bookmarklet

I find myself having to interact with a web page that hides state in various places so that one cannot easily share it as a URL, for example this page which allows users to look up information from city zoning applications:

> https://aca.cityofberkeley.info/community/Default.aspx

You can interact with the page all you want, but the URL in the location bar will remain the same as the above.

Currently, city staff provide users with instructions like "Load this URL, click on the 'Zoning' tab, enter DRCP2020-0010 under the 'Permit Number' field, click 'Search', then when the records come up, click 'Record Info' and then select 'Attachments' from the dropdown menu, then click on the PDF document that says '2020-10-21_DRCP_APP_PCKT_2801 Adeline.pdf'". I would like to be able to replace these instructions with a URL.

Another example is the website where video from city council meetings is archived:

> http://berkeley.granicus.com/MediaPlayer.php?publish_id=cbebb4e6-5b83-11eb-920e-0050569183fa

It would be nice to be able to produce a link which brings up one of the meeting videos, and seeks to a certain timestamp like 53:40, so that I can refer to something specific that was said at a meeting.

Looking at the pages that are loaded when I follow the instructions in each case, I can see that there are some POST forms, cookies, hidden input fields, and so on.

Is there some kind of tool that I can use to create "deep links" to pages like these, that were generated using non-URL hidden state, which will allow me to quickly share what I'm looking at with another user?

What I'm seeking is similar to the [frmget](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/forms.html) "bookmarklet", which changes the forms on a page to use GET instead of POST. Sometimes this succeeds in producing a URL which captures form submission query parameters. However, it doesn't work for these applications, for whatever reason.

This question is possibly related to the idea of [capturing a web page's DOM state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447830/how-to-capture-current-visual-state-of-page) [using "browser screenshots" and a script called `html2canvas`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-in-browser-screenshots). A possible solution might involve [getting and setting cookies in a bookmarklet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032186/bookmarklet-for-set-and-read-cookies). Ideally something that produces a normal "https://" URL would be ideal, but if it is impossible to solve the problem except by outputting a "javascript:" URL (bookmarklet) then that is acceptable to me (in spite of the security implications). Thanks.

Comment: It is possible to load and save a page's state in the URL's [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) or [URI fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16907861/975097).

Comment: @AndersonGreen If your point is that query strings are accessible in JavaScript, then your comment seems to underestimate the question. But if you think I am missing something, then you are welcome to submit an answer that fills in your thoughts on how to solve the linking problem for the two example websites.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like not a programming matter. It seems like the site has some security issues as well.

**QUESTION A: About Zoning**

Here are some links you can use

1. Direct link to Zoning (I've found it via Advanced search from the site):

https://aca.cityofberkeley.info/CitizenAccess/Cap/CapHome.aspx?module=Planning&TabName=Planning&TabList=Home%7C0%7CBuilding%7C1%7CHousing%7C2%7CPlanning%7C3%7CFire%7C4%7CLicenses%7C5%7CPublicWorks%7C6%7CCurrentTabIndex%7C3

2. A strange link to the list of files (I've found it via downloading a file, then going to `chrome://downloads`, then right-clicking the file I've download. The link has been the following):

https://aca.cityofberkeley.info/CitizenAccess/FileUpload/AttachmentsList.aspx?iframeid=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_attachmentEdit&module=Planning&isInConfirm=False&isdetail=True&isaccountmanager=False&isAdmin=True&isPeopleDocument=&agencyCode=BERKELEY&isForConditionDocument=N

It still doesn't give the direct link to the file, but it it gives the list of attachement of the previously opened Zoning record.

Currently I have no idea what file is triggered by `javascipt:__doPostBack('attachmentList$gdvAttachmentList$ctl02$lnkFileName','')`.

In any case, based on what we have, step one, and then step two seems like minimize the path to download the file. I guess there could be a way to download the file directly, but I currently don't see any easy way. Maybe someone else could figure it out.

**QUESTION B: About video**

I've used an `embed` link that shows all the attributes that can be used.

There is a pretty strange but working way to give the exact timestamp. Change `starttime` from the link below:

https://berkeley.granicus.com/MediaPlayer.php?publish_id=cbebb4e6-5b83-11eb-920e-0050569183fa&starttime=0&stoptime=undefined&autostart=1

So replacing `0` for `3600` will rewind the video forward by one hour (3600 seconds):

https://berkeley.granicus.com/MediaPlayer.php?publish_id=cbebb4e6-5b83-11eb-920e-0050569183fa&starttime=3600&stoptime=undefined&autostart=1

The problem here is that ... you cannot rewind back manually that particular hour (it just gets kind cropped out). But it works to show the exact episode.

That's a pretty strange site.