# document.cookie for another URL?

Tags: javascript, cookies

How would I grab the cookies from another URL in Javascript through `document.cookie`?

For example, the browser is at `http://google.com/`, and I want it to grab the cookies stored for `http://stackoverflow.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to grab cookies for other websites, that's against browsers security policies.

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834436/how-to-get-cookies-from-a-different-domain-with-php-and-javascript)

[Google Chrome Extension](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies)

Comment: Wasn't much help, I should've mentioned I'm doing this on a chrome extension, so there are a few setbacks.

Comment: Also should've mentioned I've done that, but it returns undefined no matter what. I guess I should update the OP...

Comment: Did you use the: 
chrome.cookies.getAll(object details, function callback) function...

Comment: No, chrome.cookies.get().