# Set a cookie on the other language domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my website, we have 2 domains. One for every language.

```
www.mysite.com

en.mysite.com
```

Is it possible with JavaScript to set a cookie on en.mysite.com if i click a link in www.mysite.com?

My current code :

```
$.cookie("redirectLanguage", "fr", { expires: 365,domain: '/' });
```

If so, what is the best solution to achieve this ? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting setting cookies on different domains, with javascript or other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402348/getting-setting-cookies-on-different-domains-with-javascript-or-other)

Comment: This solutions seems to work only in firefox...

Answer (score 0):

You should add dot in front of the domain name, for your example it would be:

```
$.cookie("redirectLanguage", "fr", { expires: 365,domain: '.mysite.com' });
```

Comment: i tried it but the cookie is only set in .mysite.com and not en.mysite.com

Comment: @ArnaudAd Cookies, which starts with dot should be able across all subdomains, try to clear your current cookies and set the new one again.